# How to check length of characters in 2 different text fields & show a preview, seem to be a conflict

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm coding a search engine preview tool, similar to [this](https://www.portent.com/serp-preview-tool). Instead of measuring pixels, the tool should count the number of character in the text box. Also, a preview of the values entered will be shown.

The 'Meta Description' text input works but not the 'SEO Title' input, how do I fix it? Also should I do this with less lines of code, I feel like I'm repeating myself.

Here's the Javascript:

```
// On keyUp, check & preview Title
function yourElemOnKeyup(titleCheckPreview){
   checkLength(title);
   preview(title);
}

// Title character count more than 70
function checkLength(title) {
  var strText = title.value;
  strText = strText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

if(strText.length > 70) {
  title.style.backgroundColor = "#F88379";
} else {
  title.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
 }
}

// Title SERP Preview
function preview(title){
  var inputBox = document.getElementById('title');
  document.getElementById('seoTitle').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}

// On keyUp, check & preview Meta Description
function yourElemOnKeyup(descrCheckPreview){
       checkLength(description);
       preview(description);
   
}

// Meta Description count more than 150
function checkLength(description) {
 var strText = description.value;
 strText = strText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

 if(strText.length > 150) {
  description.style.backgroundColor = "#F88379";
 } else {
  description.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
 }
}

// Meta Description SERP Preview
function preview(description){
  var inputBox = document.getElementById('description');
  document.getElementById('metaDescription').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
};
```

Here's the HTML:

```
URL: <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="site.com/slug-less-than-5-words" style="width: 315px;" placeholder="Add comments:" onkeyup="document.getElementById('urlSlug').innerHTML = this.value"></br>

SEO Title: <input type="text" id="title" name="title" style="width: 315px;" placeholder="Titles truncated after approx. 70 characters" onkeyup="yourElemOnKeyup(this.titleCheckPreview)"></br>

Meta Description: <input type="text" id="description" name="description" style="width: 315px;" placeholder="Descriptions truncated after approx. 150 characters" onkeyup="yourElemOnKeyup(this.descrCheckPreview)"></br>
    
        SERP Preview:
    <div id="seoTitle"></div>
    <div id="urlDomain"></div>
    <div id="urlSlug"></div>
    <div id="metaDescription"></div>
```

Comment: Been trying to understand your code for 10 minutes... Just gonna say that the two `onkeyup="yourElemOnKeyup(this.descrCheckPreview)"` you have, use an object property(which is undefined) as an argument to functions that do nothing with that argument. Also `function preview(title)` is the same as `function preview(description)` just with another argument. You should either create a function to work with both, or two separated.

Comment: Thanks so much @yuriy636! I'm a total noob, your advice really helped me. Now it works after changing the functions.